# What is a good file type for campatibility with blender

Tags: import, file-format

I have written a program for segmenting fluorescent microscopy images in java. The result are triangulated meshes. I would like to export the meshes to a filetype that is compatible with blender.

My main criteria is an open API or file structure that I can use.

How can I save mesh data for multiple meshes into a file that blender can read?

Answer (score 3):

I think Wavefront .obj is what you're looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file

As far as I know, Blender imports an obj file as one single object, so you may have to separate them later.

Comment: I made a PLY exporter, but blender doesn't seem to respect the color attribute.

Answer (score 2):

obj, fbx, 3ds, bvh, dae, ply, stl all work with blender. In my own experience OBJ works with the smallest amount of issues